# Something's up with the network indicator

Tags: wingpanel, wifi, suspend, internet

The network indicator in the wingpanel has been behaving strangely lately. Every now and then it would just display the icon stating that I'm not connected to the Internet (as seen in the screenshot below), and not display any networks when I click on it. This usually happens when the computer returns from suspend/sleep mode, but not always and a reboot always fixes the problem.
[image]

As you can see, Skype and Dropbox are both connected and working fine and so does everything else that requires the Internet, but the indicator just doesn't show it. A restart always fixes the issue, but I'd like to fix this for good.
Any ideas? I'll appreciate any input on this.

Thanks!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

This should reset the NM Service and return the correct icon.

Comment: Worked like a charm :). At least now I've got a quicker workaround than rebooting. Hopefully, a fix will be introduced and I won't have to keep doing that almost every time I resume from sleep. Thanks!!